# THREE.js + video-mapping

Tags: three.js

Is there a way to control 'properties' when mapping a video to a mesh in THREE.js in webGL (i.e,.the video "texture" is not aligned where i would like on the mesh/is this something that can only be handled through UV-mapping in Blender or other modeling program?)-I am loading a video programmatically as 'texture' onto a simple 3d model. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly change the UVs of your `three.js` mesh, and as a result, control the alignment of your video texture.

Here is an example where that is done: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_materials_video.html

Comment: thanks SO much for your prompt response! yes, i saw this example/ i am trying to use webRTC to map video over a 3d mesh  and it seems like a lot of trial and error to position/align properly .

Comment: after experimenting lots with spherical shapes (and this example: http://www.adrienbaptiste.com/webcam/) i am unable to alter the webcam view mapped on to the sphere (i would like to; for example; magnify or zoom the view shown on a sphere to show only an eye)--can you suggest any resources or ideas?

Comment: thank you for your help-i have experimented with this example: (http://www.adrienbaptiste.com/webcam/) but there is little i can do to affect the view that the webcam is projecting onto the sphere (for example; i would like to zoom/magnify so that only an 'eye' would map to the sphere). Can you suggest any further tips or info? thank you.

Comment: _Please_ do not un-accept an answer and then follow up with more questions. Instead, post a new issue... Like I said, within the framework of three.js, you can only change the `faceVertexUVs` of your sphere to achieve the effect you want. If you are having trouble visualizing the UVs, have a look a this thread: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1683, where you will find a link to a three.js UV helper. I hope you will now find this answer "acceptable" again.